# Hide contact's name when sending an email

Tags: email, contacts, gmail

I am using somewhat "unofficial" names for people I work with in my Address Book.
Basically, I add an emoji after the first name to help me recognize the contact faster (extremely helpful on the iPhone and on my email app on desktop - my contacts are synced between my mac and my iPhone..).

The thing is that somehow when I send an email to someone he see himself the way I saved him, resulting in an awkward situations sometimes... And even If I send an email to a colleague and he forward that email - the name with my emoji stays!

Is there a way to hide the way I save contacts when I am sending an email? I know that an email can have a First and Last name attached to it as default, can I show this somehow?

I am using Gmail account, Unibox app for mac to send emails, and all my contacts are synced between my devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use the nickname field instead.
afaik, that doesn't transmit. (At least, no one's ever complained to me about what I call them ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the only answer is to always BCC my contacts, because then the names I have given them in my address book will not appear. It seems very strange to me now that recipients can see information from our address book, I haven't noticed it untill a contact for weirded out by his strange coded name I'd given him for my address book to be more useful.